# How to integrate ffmpeg with gltransition?

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, glew, mesa

I want to build FFMPEG with GLTransition filter. I followed the build instructions from [this link](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition)

I also installed all the dependencies for FFMPEG build(GLU & GLEW libs) and configured it with EGL.

My configured command is:

```
./configure --extra-libs='-lGLEW -lEGL' --enable-filter=gltransition --disable-x86asm
```

After executing this command in Enabled Filter log GLTransition filter is there.
I have checked for GLTransition filter using command:

```
./ffmpeg -v 0 -filters | grep gltransition
```

but it shows nothing.

Then also cross checked using ffmpeg command below:

```
./ffmpeg -i media/0.mp4 -i media/1.mp4 -filter_complex gltransition -y out.mp4
```

but it shows error like,

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x1febe80] No such filter: 'gltransition'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument.
```

Am I missed something?